# Most Efficient Way to Search for "Bad Names" in a User's Name

Tags: php, regex

I have an app that I'm developing, in it users can choose a name for themselves.  I need to be able to filter out "bad" names, so I do this for now:

```
$error_count=0;

$bad_names="badname1badname2";

preg_match_all("/\b".$user_name."\b/i",$global['bad_names'],
  $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if(count($matches[0])>0)
{
  $error_count++;
}
```

This would tell me if the user's name was inside the bad names list, however, it doesn't tell me if the bad name itself is in the user's name.  They could combine a bad word with something else and I wouldn't detect it.

What kind of regex (if I even use regex) would I use for this?  I need to be able to take any bad name (preferably in an array like $bad_names), and search through the user's name to see whether that word is within their name.  I'm not great with regex, and the only way I can think of is to put it all through a loop which seems highly inefficient.  Anyone have a better idea?  I guess I need to figure out how to search through a string with an array.

Comment: I did try to edit my post to put the code lines in but you beat me to it mellamokb :P

Comment: Somewhere I have read a useful comic/article about how simple "bad word" filtering can mess things up and catch harmless words.  Of course, I can't find it now of course.

Comment: @SurrealDreams [A Clbuttic Mistake](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html)

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had "butt" in it.  Well done, JT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$badnames = array('name1', 'name2');

// you need to quote the names so they can be inserted into the
// regular expression safely
$badnames_quoted = array();
foreach ($badnames as $name) {
    $badnames_quoted[] = preg_quote($name, '/');
}

// now construct a RE that will match any bad name
$badnames_re = '/\b('.implode('|', $badnames_quoted).')\b/Siu';

// no need to gather all matches, or even to see what matched
$hasbadname = preg_match($badnames_re, $thestring);
if ($hasbadname) {
    // bad name found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static $bad_name = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
private static $forbidden_name = array (array of unwanted character strings)

private static function userNameValid($name_in) {
  $badFound = preg_match("/\b(" . implode(self::$bad_name,"|") . ")\b/i", $name_in); // checks array for exact match
  $forbiddenFound = preg_match("/(" . implode(self::$forbidden_name,"|") . ")/i", $name_in); // checks array for any character match with a given name (i.e. "ass" would be found in assassin)

  if ($badFound) {
     return FALSE;
  } elseif ($forbiddenFound) {
     return FALSE;
  } else {
     return TRUE;
  }
```

This works GREAT for me